# Moving the "keywords" section in achemso package

Tags: formatting, keywords, achemso

I am working on a re-submission for an ACS journal using the `achemso` package, and one of the requests from the editorial board was to move the "keywords" section to the first page (i.e. above the "abstract" section). Is there a simple way to accomplish this without going into the package and changing things, which I don't even know how to do since I'm relatively inexperienced with LaTeX? I contacted the editorial board but their response was, "As long as the key words are located on page one it does not matter..."

A MWE is:

```
    \documentclass[journal=aamick, manuscript=article]{achemso}
    \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{textgreek}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
    \usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}

    \author{Author 1}
    \affiliation[Institute]{Address 1}
    \author{Author 2}
    \affiliation[Institute]{Address 1}
    \author{Author 3}
    \affiliation[Institute]{Address 1}
    \alsoaffiliation[Other Department]{Address 2}

    \title{Document Title}

    \keywords{keyword 1; keyword 2; keyword 3; keyword 4; keyword 5}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{abstract}

    \end{document}
```

Any help getting the keywords onto the title page would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's quite strange that the editorial board requires `achemso` and asks a user to modify it.

Comment: @egreg No, I'm afraid it's not: each editorial office is a law until itself!

Comment: Have you got a mail from the editorial office you can forward to me? I like to have something reasonably 'official' before making changes ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could force output of the keywords before the abstract, e.g., using:

```
\documentclass[journal=aamick, manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}

\author{Author 1}
\affiliation[Institute]{Address 1}
\author{Author 2}
\affiliation[Institute]{Address 1}
\author{Author 3}
\affiliation[Institute]{Address 1}
\alsoaffiliation[Other Department]{Address 2}

\title{Document Title}

\keywords{keyword 1; keyword 2; keyword 3; keyword 4; keyword 5}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\forcekeywords}{
  \acs@keywords@print
  \let\acs@keywords@print\relax
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\forcekeywords

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

But, I think, the result:

[image: ugly result]

would be very ugly.

A better solution would be to shorten the abstract:

```
\documentclass[journal=aamick, manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}

\author{Author 1}
\affiliation[Institute]{Address 1}
\author{Author 2}
\affiliation[Institute]{Address 1}
\author{Author 3}
\affiliation[Institute]{Address 1}
\alsoaffiliation[Other Department]{Address 2}

\title{Document Title}

\keywords{keyword 1; keyword 2; keyword 3; keyword 4; keyword 5}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: Nobody likes abstracts with more than some lines. You shouldn't misuse it for an introduction with several paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you much @Schweinebacke. It works perfectly, but I will also see about trimming some of the fat in the Abstract. Best regards.